# Add text input via user selection / ajax / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've a situation : The user must select how many children they have and based on his number of children I must add Name fields for each one.

E.g User put 3 on the text field and by a button click or on onblur event I must "create" a namefield for each (in this case 3).

The thing is how do I do that? I've searched here on stackoverflow and some other forums and found nothing :/

Any thoughts?

Ty!.

Comment: Where is your attempt??? You have to post it in question itself

Comment: You can use something like `.appendTo()` in jQuery to append HTML elements (like `input` elements) to the DOM.  There's no AJAX here, just handling a button click and adding HTML elements to the DOM.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't found nothing and I'm starting with this jquery/ajax thing

Comment: `for` until the number of selected children, create an input, append to a container.

Comment: [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is your looking for something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/g78b6h7u/

```
$("#add").click(function () {

    for (i = 0; i < $("#number").val();i++)
    {
        $("#appendHere").append("<input type='text' ></input>");    
    }
});
```